# Import a custom helper class in javascript React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a custom class called **helpers.js** which looks like this:

```
class Httprequest{
    constructor(type, url, username, password,email){
        this.type = type;
        this.url = url;
        this.request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }
    static sendPostRequest(){

        // function(method,url,async,user,password);
        this.request.open(this.type,this.url);
        this.request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type' ,'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        const data = encodeURI('username=' + this.username + '&'+
                                'password=' + this.password + '&'+
                                'email=' + this.email);
        this.request.send(data);
        if(this.request.readyState === 4){
            const status = this.request.status;
                if(status === 201){
                    return this.request.status;
                }else{
                    return "Failed creating account"
                }
        }
    }

}

export default Httprequest;
```

Then I'm trying to import the class in my React Component called **Projects.js**

```
import Httprequest from 'helpers.js';
```

I get error which looks like this:
Failed to compile.

```
./src/components/Projects.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'helpers.js' in 'C:\Users\Account\Desktop\front\frontend\src\components'
```

Both files are in the same folder, what gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try:

```
import Httprequest from './helpers.js';
```

You need to explicitly indicate your current folder like this.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Does the syntax './helpers.js' mean it will go one folder back? Do I always have to add the ./ in front to import classes?

Comment: great. the syntax './helpers.js' means the same folder. It is Unix like file system structure. '../helpers.js' would mean the folder above, and '../../helpers.js' two folders above.

Comment: Oh, so the amount of dots actually matters. Thank you!

Comment: Just a quick note that you probably don't want to add the `.js` file extension in your import.

Answer (score 1):

Here are all types of import syntax:

```
import defaultExport from "module-name";
import * as name from "module-name";
import { export } from "module-name";
import { export as alias } from "module-name";
import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";
import { export1 , export2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, { export [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, * as name from "module-name";
import "module-name";
```

The problem with your import is that you need to use `./helpers.js` if in the same directory. It's same as UNIX file system structure.

Comment: Visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 import Httprequest from './helpers.js';
```